# Android App Gradle Build error "Could not find com.github.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.2"

Tags: android, build, build.gradle, android-build

I am trying to build an Android App, which has dependency on **SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library** . The build of the app is getting failed with below error -

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.2.
     Required by:
         project
```

Below is the code where I have included its dependency in build.gradle(app)-

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.2'
}
```

I have added maven repository also  -

```
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
```

**My Trial:**
After so many hit and try , I found that if I compile with the dependency on previous version of the library than there is no issue. So below code is working for me -

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.1'
}
```

**Problem Summary:** I want to include the latest version of SFG that is 1.2 , but build is failing. However build is passing with previous version of SFG Lib that is 1.1.

**Note:** I am not using AndroidStudio for build, but using command line gradlew utility (because of other Code dependencies). However I have tried with Android Studio also issue is same.

Answer (score 9):

you should add `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` in **settings.gradle** file.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `com.github.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.2` to `in.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.2`, based on [the project documentation](https://github.com/championswimmer/SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library).

Comment: I have tried this still build error is there `Could not find in.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.2.` . However if I use same for 1.1 version (i.e. `in.championswimmer:SimpleFingerGestures_Android_Library:1.1`) than no error.

Comment: @shivi: Make sure that your change to `repositories` is to the *right* `repositories` -- in a standard Android Studio project, it would be the one in `allprojects` in the top-level `build.gradle` file. Beyond that, make sure that you are following the project documentation, then contact the project developer if you continue to have problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
//add in both place
buildscript {
    repositories {
         ....
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
     .......
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```